# Filtering array with specified value fails to return a new array

Tags: vue.js, underscore.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having trouble trying to assign a new array after filtering. Every time I filter, it returns an empty array. The statement works however on other arrays but not the one I want to filter. I'm using Vue and Underscore

```
// HTML

<el-button @click="searchHashtag('#hr')>Test</el-button>

// JS

data: () {
     return {
           // this is my array. an array of objects
          messages = [{ 
               _id = "1",
               hashtags = [ "hr" ] },

               {_id = "2",
               hashtags = [ "hr", "#acc" ] },

               {_id = "3",
               hashtags = [] }]
       }

methods: {
     // this is suppose to return assign a new array to messages
     // after it filters it's old values
     searchHashtag (searchBy) {
          this.messages = _.filter(this.messages, 
               _.compose(_.partial(_.contains, _, searchBy), 
               _.property('hashtags')))
```

I tried the function in another array like so and it gave a return:

```
var messages = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    hashtag: ["#cool"]
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Bob",
    hashtag: ["#cool", "#sweet"]
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Bob",
    hashtag: ["#sweet"]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the term **#hr** but no items in your **messages** array contain this term in the **hashtags** array.

They include only **hr**, without the **#**.

This is why your filtered array is empty.

Comment: You have fixed the code in the question so now it does not make sense. Are you able to revert the question and accept the answer if it has helped?